# Notepadd++ Block Uncomment

Tags: keyboard, notepad++, shortcut

Is there a way to set the keyboard shortcut for Block Uncomment in Notepad++? I've searched through the list in Settings->Shortcut Mapper but I can only find a setting for Block Comment.

Answer (score 23):

Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> for block comment
and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> for block uncomment

You might find [this](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Notepad-plus-plus_5.9.html) site useful.

Comment: @Grijan Those keyboard shortcuts work for me. v7.9.1

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> can be used for toggling between the comment and uncomment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answering questions here is good but please read the question. Control+Q is for toggling a single-line comment (checked in Notepad++ 7.9.5). The questions asks about block comments and that was answered over 7 years ago. New answers to old questions should add new insights and new information, repeating old answers is not helpful.

Comment: lower case q (not  Q) is the correct answer.

Comment: Either case (q or Q) works. Tested on Notepad++ 8.3.3